# SQL Server connecting to another SQL server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, linked-server

So I have 2 SQL servers, both internal on the firewall, and my webserver is on the DMZ.  The webserver currently connects to one of the SQL servers for it's data.

I need some information from the other SQL server which I cannot connect to from the DMZ because of security risks that the company is not willing to take.

How can I connect to one SQL server to another to obtain certain information for particular rows in a database on the first?

So basically what I need to do is:

Server 1 has database "db1" which has a table "tbl" with fields "field1,field2,field3"

I need to populate "field3" from data obtained from Server 2 using a query.

Is this possible?

If not, how else can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at linked servers.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can set up and use linked servers.

Answer (score 0):

you can either create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) or use [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to link the servers, to pull off what you are trying to do.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx